# Annotating macOS Maps locations with personal notes

Tags: notes.app, metadata, maps, macos

I’d like to annotate map locations with “check out this art piece when you’re at this gallery” or “my favourite is the bibimbap” for a restaurant. It would be *really* cool to be able to link to a Notes.app note.

Is there a built-in way to do this with Apple Maps’ guides?

Comment: I’m tagging this macOS - please update the tags if you need other platforms for these apps or just delete macOS if it’s wrong. The iCloud tag would be appropriate if you need these annotations to sync and they do not. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For Notes.app: in Apple Maps select location, on pop-up window click on three dots in right upper corner, select Share -> Notes:

[image]

Add annotation(s) to note and choose whether it will be added to existing note or new one will be created:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to be able to be able to use Maps as the “base layer” of the tooling to be used and be able to create a guide like the “Discover America’s National Parks” guide that makes a list of annotated locations that can be scrolled through and visited.